# Iterating over different divs in Javascript and passing arguments to a script

Tags: javascript, php, html

#### Background

I am using PHP to created a list of voting sections. Each section is the same except for a unique number, which increases by `1` each time the PHP loops.

I use the PHP variable `$n` as a counter, and place that in the `id` attributes in several places in each section.

#### Current PHP/HTML:

```
echo "<div id='votesection'>";
echo "<h3 id='rating " . $n . "' style='display:block;'>" . 
echo "<h3 id='ratingup " . $n . "' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingup . "</h3>\r\n";
echo "<h3 id='ratingdown " . $n . "' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingdown . "</h3>\r\n";
echo "<div class='arrow-down' onclick='downvote($n)'></div>\r\n";
echo "<div class='arrow-up' onclick='upvote($n)'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

#### Goal

When a user clicks on an arrow down or arrow up, certain `div`s are hidden or displayed. Example, when the up arrow in my second section is clicked, my `<h3 id='ratingup2'></h3>` would change to visible.

#### Current JS

```
 function upvote() {
    // Script to hide rating, and rating down and display:block ratingup
    // Will also need to execture php sql query to increment event rating by one for event by one
 }

function downvote(){
    // Same script but to show rating down and decrement rating
 }
```

Should I pass every rating id to the script or is there an easier way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: what is $n? is it the id?what do you mean by "adding each id to the script?

You shouldn't have spaces in the id eg "rating 34234" you should have "description_id".I m sure you are going to get an error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2321666

Comment: Correct, sorry formatting error with the space. It should be rating0, rating1, rating2, etc etc. Since each votesection will have a different number, I'd assumed to identify each rating it would be best to give them different ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the ID is the easiest way to do it with plain Javascript.

```
function upvote(n) {
    document.getElementById('ratingup ' + n).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('ratingdown ' + n).style.display="none";
}
function downvote(n) {
    document.getElementById('ratingup ' + n).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('ratingdown ' + n).style.display="block";
}
```

A way to do it without passing the ID would be to put classes on the rating DIVs, and pass `this` instead.

HTML:

```
echo "<div id='votesection'>";
echo "<h3 id='rating " . $n . "' style='display:block;'>" . 
echo "<h3 class='ratingup' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingup . "</h3>\r\n";
echo "<h3 class='ratingdown' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingdown . "</h3>\r\n";
echo "<div class='arrow-down' onclick='downvote(this)'></div>\r\n";
echo "<div class='arrow-up' onclick='upvote(this)'></div>";
```

JS:

```
function upvote(self) {
    var parent = self.parentNode;
    parent.querySelector(".ratingup").style.display = "block";
    parent.querySelector(".ratingdown").style.display = "none";
}
function downvote(self) {
    var parent = self.parentNode;
    parent.querySelector(".ratingup").style.display = "none";
    parent.querySelector(".ratingdown").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, the parentNode would be the votesection? This would change only the selected ratings within that votesection, and not other votesections on the page correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. `parentNode` is the DOM element that contains this element. Using that as the context to `querySelector` only finds the matching element within that DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You can create only one wrapper with the id votesection_id and then do everything else with js/ajax

```html
    echo "<div id='votesection_" . $n . "'>";
    echo "<h3 id='rating' style='display:block;'>" . 
    echo "<h3 id='ratingup' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingup . "</h3>\r\n";
    echo "<h3 id='ratingdown' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingdown . "</h3>\r\n";
    echo "<div class='arrow-down' onclick='downvote($n)'></div>\r\n";
    echo "<div class='arrow-up' onclick='upvote($n)'></div>";
    echo "</div>";
```

```js
<script>

    function upvote(id){
      // 1. Go To the server with ajax do your stuff  2. return the current upvotes 3.replace the upvotes h3 text
    }
    function downvote(id){
       // 1. Go To the server with ajax do your stuff  2. return the current downvotes 3.replace the downvotes h3 text
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @idioteque says in their comment, spaces in element IDs are not allowed. The best way to get this information into the document is probably with [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Also, multiple elements with the same `id` are not allowed, what you probably need in this case are `class`es. (I'm assuming this chunk of HTML will be repeated multiple times per page.)

Borrowing @Barmar's idea of passing `this` into the event handler, here's how I'd change the server code:

```
echo "<div class='votesection' data-rating-id=" . $n . ">";
echo "<h3 class='rating' style='display:block;'>" . 
echo "<h3 class='ratingup' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingup . "</h3>\r\n";
echo "<h3 class='ratingdown' style='display:none;'>" . $ratingdown . "</h3>\r\n";
echo "<div class='arrow-down' onclick='downvote(this)'></div>\r\n";
echo "<div class='arrow-up' onclick='upvote(this)'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

And the JS:

```
function upvote(self) {
    var parent = self.parentNode;
    parent.querySelector(".ratingup").style.display = "block";
    parent.querySelector(".ratingdown").style.display = "none";
    var id = parent.dataset.ratingId;
    // do your AJAX or whatever with id
}
function downvote(self) {
    var parent = self.parentNode;
    parent.querySelector(".ratingup").style.display = "none";
    parent.querySelector(".ratingdown").style.display = "block";
    var id = parent.dataset.ratingId;
    // do your AJAX or whatever with id
}
```